# Link not working because of css background image

Tags: html, css

See universal header, Call Phone Number, flush right. The phone # link is not working where ever it overlaps the css background image. If I resize the window to mobile view, the link is active again where ever it does not overlap the background image.

https://www.pavillon.org/

I've modified the z-indexes but no luck. Same result across different browsers. Any insight?

https://www.pavillon.org/

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what else to add. Here is the HTML - 
          
<a href="tel:+18286942300">We’re Here For You - For Life</a>
<br>
<i class="fas fa-phone-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 Call 
<a href="tel:+18286942300">828-694-2300</a>

Comment: That information goes in your question, not down here. See [ask], at least, if you don't have the ambition to read those other pages.

Comment: By the way, background images do not cover things. _Elements_ do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the devtools I was able to add `z-index:100` of `.brand-container` and it works fine now.  Just make that element have a higher `z-index` so it appears on top of that image.

Comment: Please don't answer the question until they've fulfilled the requirement of an [mcve]. At this point you've given the OP no reason to do this, making the question useless to future visitors.

Comment: Thank you kindly to FiniteLooper. That was the issue. Apologies to the moderator, as I didn't have anymore information to provide. Grateful for the assistance.